# Beergas or just c02

Tags: kegging, co2, gas

I've recently come across there being beergas or G-Mix and co2.  I had originally thought that it was just co2 and not a mixture of co2 and nitrogen.

What are the issues with just using co2?

Answer (score 3):

Most draft systems for homebrewers use just normal CO2.
The beer gas of N2 and CO2 is used for 'nitro' dispense depending on the N2/CO2 ratio.

Answer (score 3):

As brewchez stated it mostly for stouts with a nitro faucet in the homebrew world.

But Beergas is preferred commercially if a tap run is really long. The Beergas allows them to push at much higher psi without overcarbonating beer along the way, for all styles of beer.